# Can't delete migration entry from DB after manually deleting the table (laravel)

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I removed one table manually because of some mess with migrations and now I can't migrate because the table is set as already migrated (there's the entry in the migration table in the DB).
The problem is there is not any delete option for the entries under migration.
A warning appears like this: "This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available"
So how do I remove the entry?

Answer (score 0):

solved by setting a primary key for the "migration" column.